# How do I download documents from SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to download all documents and their versions from a SharePoint Online site.

I have tried achieving this by using a script by Nik Craik that I found [here](http://www.nikcraik.ca/sharepoint-powershell-script-to-extract-all-documents-and-their-versions/).
It doesn't work because it keeps throwing errors on `Get-SPWeb` commands. I suspect this is because I am using Sharepoint Online, so I replaced all instances of `Get-SPWeb` with `Get-SPOSite`.
I have confirmed that I have connected to my particular SharePoint site using `Get-SPOSite`. However, when I try this script with my modifications, I get no error reports, but there is nothing in the `C:/Export` folder.

How do I download documents and their versions from a SharePoint Online site?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly access a site collection or web in sharepoint online. Firstly you need to have context for the requested site:

```
   $loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$webUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "HTTPS URL for your SP Online 2013 site" 
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Email address for logging into that site"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" -AsSecureString


$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$web = $ctx.Web
$webs = $web.Webs
```

Courtesy: [Sharing the experience](http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.in/2013/10/sharepoint-online-and-powershell-how-to.html)

The powershell you are using is for on-premises sharepoint.

Comment: I voted your answer up but it doesn't show (not enough rep points).  I realized I needed to work with on-premises SharePoint, so your answer was hugely helpful.